# Polymorphic relation with inherited model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, polymorphic-associations

I have used polymorphic relation in one of my task having inherited models like

```
Class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
end

Class Company < Organization
  has_many :roles, as: :authorizable
end

Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles, as: :authorizable
end

Class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :authorizable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

When I try to fetch `User.find(user_id).roles`, it gives me correct result; however, when I try to query like `Company.find(company_id).roles`, it gives me blank array as it queries like

```
SELECT * FROM `roles` WHERE (`roles`.authorizable_id = 5 AND `roles`.authorizable_type = 'Organization')
```

It should be like 'authorizable_type' = 'Company'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try setting `self.table_name = "Company"` inside your company model. 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-table_name

Comment: But table doesn't exist with name 'company'. Only model exist

Comment: I think that's what happens when you use a inherited model, how did you add data of company's roles?  you wrote authorizable_type property to 'Company' by hard code?

Comment: It was hard coded before i have started working on it.

Comment: So that's the problem, you should build relations like that: company.roles << roles. Then it will be ok.

Comment: But it would be on database entry time, but what would be the case when i want to fetch records from database..?

Comment: I think company.roles << roles then company.roles will be fine. Open you rails console and have a try.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are doing anything wrong. The code seems to be using single table inheritance. `Organization` and its subclasses share the same database table, but are distinguished by the value of the `type` column (for `Company` the `type` will be `"Company"`).

In a polymorphic relation with single table inheritance, the `authorizable_type` will always be the name of the parent model (`"Organization"`).

See [here](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html).